# How much deeper sink can I get away with without having to redo waste drain?

Tags: kitchens, drain, sink

I'm remodeling the kitchen. Our sink is a standard 7" deep sink, but most cool sinks these days are 8-10" deep. I would probably want to keep the existing configuration with the double bowl and disposal. It looks like I could *maybe* squeak out an extra 1.5 inches by shortening the tailpiece below the sink. I think modifying the plumbing stub out so the trap arm could be lower would be a pain because this is an exterior wall below the window.

[image: sink image]

Here's a picture with the measure up to the bottom of the sink.

[image: sink image 2]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Good picture, but could you do one showing the bottom of the current sink, with the tape measure all the way up?

Comment: How long is the tailpiece from bottom of sink to top of the tee?

Comment: I think the tailpiece from the sink to the tee, can't be shortened because you need the difference because of the disposal. As far as the drain piece in the wall, could be easy. You just need to cut the drywall out there, and see how far or easy it would be to cut the pipe down. Only problem there I could see is that then you need to add a section to go up to the vent (if you have a vent tied directly on to the sink drain.) Since you plan to remodel...why not just cut the drywall there anyway? You can patch it and make it pretty again, or not worry as it is under the sink.

Comment: Jeff, yeah I think that's what I may end up doing (modifying the drain). I just need to learn how to do plumbing :P.

Answer (score 1):

You've got 3" of trap seal and you are allowed 4" (3" is better) and there is about 1-1/2" of space between the tee and the coupling nut. For a grand total of 2-1/2". You may be able to squeeze more with some reconfiguration but it seems you really need to.

If you need that extra inch you'll need to change the trap to abs and use a rubberized coupling like a Fernco coupling. The abs trap would need to be a hub trap (basically a U shape) with no union. This will allow you to make a 4" trap seal.

**This shows where you can get the full two and a half inches**
[image]

**Hub trap**
[image]
[Hogwart](http://hogwart-rpg.info/abs-p-trap/abs-p-trap-tap-to-expand-15-abs-trap-adapter/)

Instead of using the 90°(street 90) as shown use a section of pipe sufficient to create a 4" trap seal and turn the street 90 around and attach to the wall stub with the rubberized coupling. On the other side (tailpiece side) use a tailpiece adapter and a section of pipe. Done!